# jquery .toggle() won't start before triple-click

Tags: jquery, google-maps, toggle, slide

I'm trying to slide in a google map on top of my [page](http://www.bergdreh.de) when the map-button is clicked. It works perfectly but not before clicking the map-button three times. Here is my - maybe awkward - code:

```
$(function(){
$("#schalter, #koordinaten").toggle(function(){

    $("#ueberkarte").animate({
        width:'100%',
        opacity: 'show',    
        left: '0'                   
        }, 'slow');
}, function() {

$('#ueberkarte').animate({
    width: 'hide',
    opacity: 'hide'
}, 'slow');});});
```

I would appreciate very much if someone told me what I'm doing wrong or how I could accomplish it easier.
thanks in advance,
Thomas

Comment: just in case - my solution:
`$('#schalter, #koordinaten').click(function() {
    $('#ueberkarte').animate({left: 'toggle'});
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery toggle function is defined as:

```
.toggle( [duration] [, easing] [, callback] )
```

- duration is a String or number representing the time for the animation
- easing is the animation type as String
- callback is a function which is called when all animation is finished

The common way is to define a click handler on the buttons and then define the toggle function in the click callback. The toggle function also hides you element and you don't need a additional animation. You can simply do something like this:

```
$('#schalter').click(function() {
    $('#ueberkarte').toggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: Hey Soc,
thank you, that looks good. But using your code the map is "turned on" when the page is loaded. I need the map to be hidden in the beginning.

Comment: You can hide with css the #ueberkarte. So it is default hidden and the script will display it. `#ueberkarte {display: none;}`

Answer (score 0):

Hy, german college ;-)
I can't read any click event or something else in your code. 
 Maybe you should try

```
$('#ueberkarte').on("click",function(){
//Moving Up and Down of you google map
});
```

Comment: Hey neighbour, thank you. The Click-Event was actually missing.